# What is the time complexity of the below function?

Tags: c, big-o, time-complexity

```
void fun(int n, int arr[])
{
int i = 0, j = 0;
for(; i < n; ++i)
    while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j])
        j++;
}
```

The answer given is: variable j is not initialized for each value of variable i, so time complexity is O(n)

I don't quite understand it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: the j loop only runs once, hence the single pass O(n)..

Comment: minor nitpick: it should read the time complexity is **in** O(n), the big O notation always denotes a Set of complexities, and the complexity of a given algorithm can only be a member of the set, and not equal to it.

Comment: The code finishes when `j` has been incremented `n` times. `j` never gets decremented, and at most `n` attempts are made at incrementing it (via `i`).

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: this abuse of terminology is so widespread, that nobody really nitpicks about it.

Comment: "Big O" is not even relevant outside algorithm theory nowadays (if it ever was), since the number of comparisons are far from the only thing that takes CPU time. Yet computer scientist dinosaurs still sit there with their "number of comparisons" while completely ignoring function call overhead, number of branches, variable data sizes, parallel execution etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

See the difference between your function and this (*this is in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity*) -

```
void fun(int n, int arr[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(; i < n; ++i)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j])
            j++;
    }
}
```

In your function the variable `j` is not initialized for each value of variable `i`. So, the inner loop runs **at most n times**.

**Edit 1-** From `j=0` to `j=n` is maximum `n` iterations of inner `while` loop. Since you never initialize `j` again once `j=n` the inner `while` loop will *never iterate*. So at maximum (*it could be less depending on the second condition `arr[i] < arr[j]`*) you have `n` iterations of inner `while` loop **once**. The outer `for` loop will obviously iterate `n` times . So you have `n+n=2n` and not `n`<sup>`2`</sup> even in the worst case.

**Edit 2-**  *@Kerrek SB* answer to this is spot-on - 
*"The code finishes when `j` has been incremented `n` times. `j` never gets decremented, and at most `n` attempts are made at incrementing it (via `i`)"*

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is executed `n` times.

The inner loop only continues if `j < n`, and since `j` is incremented in each step, it cannot be executed more than `n` times in total.